# How to get Beanshell assertion name

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

[image: Beanshell Assertion]

How can i get Beanshell Assertion name (`Schema: Test.json`) into variable?

Comment: Explain more, Why you want to get the name? What is the usage?

Comment: In Assertion i compare response with json schema. I wanna get schema name from Assertion name.

Comment: The name of the assertion is defined by yourself, why you don't hadcode it in the script? anyway, I don't get why exactly it's useful to fetch the name, but I  think it's better to define a user defined variable before BeanShell assertion and then fetch the value of that variable in the assertion.

Comment: I set name of assertion "Test.json" and i want get name of assertion as value of variable. Can i get assertion name? Because I have a few checks: (Test1.json, Test2.json, ...) Where Test1.json - json file with schema. I want change only assertion name, without change beanshel script in assertion.